# python - using list comprehension with an or clause

Tags: python

So I'm trying to convert a dictionary into a list, and at the same time I want to get the keys that do not contain certain keywords. I tried doing something like this(see below) but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any ideas how to do this?

```
[(key,value) for key, value in album.items() if ('available_markets' not in key) or ('images' not in key)]
```

EDIT: album data should look something like this:

```
album ={'album_group': 'album', 'album_type': 'album', 'artists_0_external_urls_spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2', 'artists_0_href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2', 'artists_0_id': '3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2', 'artists_0_name': 'The Beatles', 'artists_0_type': 'artist', 'artists_0_uri': 'spotify:artist:3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2', 'available_markets_0': 'AD', 'available_markets_1': 'AE', 'images_1_width': 300, 'images_2_height': 64, 'images_2_url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/f6e12b2ef70abf43d110e5c79810655c7c3fae98', 'images_2_width': 64, 'name': 'The Beatles', 'release_date': '2018-11-09', 'release_date_precision': 'day'}
```

My attempt returned to me:

```
[('album_group', 'album'), ('album_type', 'album'), 
 ('artists_0_external_urls_spotify',
  'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2'),
 ('artists_0_href',
  'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2'),
 ('artists_0_id', '3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2'),
 ('artists_0_name', 'The Beatles'),
 ('artists_0_type', 'artist'),
 ('artists_0_uri', 'spotify:artist:3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2'),
 ('available_markets_0', 'AD'),
 ('available_markets_1', 'AE'),
 ('images_1_width', 300),
 ('images_2_height', 64),
 ('images_2_url',
  'https://i.scdn.co/image/f6e12b2ef70abf43d110e5c79810655c7c3fae98'),
 ('images_2_width', 64),
 ('name', 'The Beatles'),
 ('release_date', '2018-11-09'),
 ('release_date_precision', 'day')]
```

I shorten the album dict but available markets can be a range from 1 to 70+ and images can be from 1 to 3. I'm just trying to filter out those keys in the new list.

Comment: Kindly provide `album` data

Comment: When you say it "doesn't seem to work", can you be more specific? What exactly are you inputting, what is it outputting, and what are you expecting?

Comment: ```[i for i in arr if i == 6 or i == 7]``` works just fine. I imagine you have a different problem.

Comment: Do you want `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi This method using `or` with `not` does not work however.

Comment: Can you elaborate? ```next = [i for i in origin if i == 2 or i not in (1, 2, 3)]``` works just fine.

Comment: Combining 2 negative tests doesn’t work. `i != 2 or i != 3` does not filter out 2 and 3 as some people may expect. `and` must be used instead of `or` here as @chepner states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the whole operation in `not` instead of each individual part:

```
[kv for kv in album.items()
 if not ('available_markets' in key or 'images' in key)]
```

Alternatively, use `and`:

```
[kv for kv in album.items()
 if 'available_markets' not in key and 'images' not in key]
```

*Thank you to [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for pointing out the use of `and` when combining negative tests.*